# Add Terminal Cut (Ctrl+k) to GPaste clipboard

Tags: shortcut-keys, paste, cut-command

I don't know if this is a local bash setting on my part, but when I cut a line within a terminal (or gnu screen) using `Ctrl+k`, the result isn't copied to GPaste.  Instead, the copied text can only be pasted within that terminal.  Is there a way to modify my .bashrc file to get the desired behavior of adding the cut text to the clipboard?

I found a solution for a Mac running zsh [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/400244/473797), but I don't know how to implement it in bash.

Comment: ctrl-shift-c  for copy and ctrl-shift-v for paste .
though I am using konsole as terminal  (and parcellite as clipboard manager)

Comment: Thanks, butCtl-Shift-c requires highlighting of the text, which requires using the mouse, Ctrl-K cuts the text to the right of the cursor, which requires no use of the mouse.